# bulk data from Truecaller with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

we have data of 2K numbers and we want to get their names via truecaller.

I used **truecallerpy** library and tried to iterate over the numbers, in this way:

```
import asyncio
from truecallerpy import search_phonenumber

 for n in numbers:
    phone_number = str(n)
    country_code = "US"
    installation_id = "Your installation ID"

    response = asyncio.run(search_phonenumber(phone_number, country_code, installation_id))
    ....
```

But after several times i got the following error:

```
{'status_code': 429, 'error': 'HTTP Error', 'message': "An HTTP error occurred: Client error '429 Too Many Requests' for url 'https://search5-noneu.truecaller.com/v2/search?q=600000038&countryCode=972&type=4&locAddr=&placement=SEARCHRESULTS%2CHISTORY%2CDETAILS&encoding=json'\nFor more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/429"}
```

I tried using the second method in the truecallerpy doc:

```
import asyncio
from truecallerpy import bulk_search

phone_numbers = "+1234567890,9876543210"
country_code = "US"
installation_id = "Installation ID"

response = asyncio.run(bulk_search(phone_numbers, country_code, installation_id))
print(response)
```

But it didn't show their names at all.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

bulk_search accepts list of phoneNumbers as argument. please check the following code

```
    import asyncio
    from truecallerpy import bulk_search
    phone_numbers = ["+1234567890", "9876543210"]
    country_code = "US"
    installation_id = "Installation ID"
    response = asyncio.run(bulk_search(phone_numbers, country_code, installation_id))
    print(response)
```